# increment operation in Systemverilog Vivado not working as expected

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

Sum: The part with the state machine named "**WaitS2**" is only incrementing the "**count**" once.

I am trying to control ultrasound sensors **HC-SR04** in **systemverilog**. As I saw in the datasheet, this sensor creates a signal "**trigger**" which creates the sound and after generating the sound sensor creates logic "**echo**", I need to count the time, so that I create the state machine you can see in the code, but the problem is count++ is not working as well as expected it is only incrementing count variable once, no matter how long the echo signal is

I used another module called 32-bit adder from internet, which did not changed anything.
I changed all of the statements to non-block statements it did not work.
I even tried changed `count++` to `count = count + 1` did not work

```
module sensorFSM(
    input logic echo , clk ,reset, 
    output logic trig,
    output logic[31:0] distance,
    output logic[1:0] presentState
    );
    /*typedef enum logic[1:0] {BeginS , WaitS , ReturnS } states;
    states presentState , nextState;
    */
    logic[31:0] count , count1; 
    logic[1:0] BeginS , WaitS, WaitS2 , ReturnS  , nextState;
    assign BeginS = 2'b00;
    assign WaitS = 2'b01; 
    assign WaitS2 = 2'b10;
    assign ReturnS = 2'b11; 

    // clk and state change
    always_ff @( posedge clk )
        begin
            if ( reset == 1'b1 )
            presentState <= BeginS;
            else
            presentState <= nextState;
        end

    // real state changes    
    always_comb 
        begin            
            case(presentState)           
            BeginS:
                begin
                    trig = 1'b1;
                    count = 32'b0;
                    nextState = WaitS;
                end
            WaitS:
                begin
                    trig = 1'b0;
                    distance = 32'b0;
                    //#5000;
                    nextState = WaitS2;
                end
            WaitS2:
                begin
                    if( echo  == 1 )
                      begin
                        if ( count < 24'b101100111000000100100000 )
                            begin 
                            // here is the problem count is only incrementing 
                            //once
                                count++;                               
                                nextState = WaitS2; 
                            end 
                         else 
                            begin
                                distance = count;
                                nextState = BeginS;
                            end 
                      end
                    else // echo == 0   
                        begin
                            nextState = ReturnS;
                        end
                   end 
            ReturnS:
                begin
                    //count =  count / 1470;
                    distance = count;
                    nextState = BeginS;
                end
            default:
                nextState = BeginS;
            endcase
         end  
endmodule
```

I expect the simulation will count like around 1 miliion but it always outputs 1, but I can see that the state named "WaitS2" is present for a long amount of time when echo is active also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an asynchronous feedback loop with `count++;` inside `always_comb`. You need to make `count` a register.

Also `trig` and `distance` are currently inferred level-sensitive latches. `distance` needs to be a flop. `trig` could be written as pure combinational logic, but since it is an output I highly recommend to make it a flop remove the rise of output glitches.

```
always_ff @( posedge clk )
    begin
      if ( reset == 1'b1 ) begin
        presentState <= BeginS;
        trig <= 0; // <-- reset
        distance <= 0; // <-- reset
        count <= 0; // <-- reset
      end else begin
        presentState <= nextState;
        trig <= next_trig; // <-- flop trig
        distance <= next_distance; // <-- flop distance
        count <= next_count; // <-- flop count
      end
    end

// real state changes    
always_comb 
    begin
      next_trig = trig; // <-- default value is flopped value
      next_distance = distance; // <-- default value is flopped value
      next_count = count; // <-- default value is flopped value
        case(presentState)           
        BeginS:
            begin
                //trig = 1'b1; // <-- is now a flop assigned in always_ff
                //count = 32'b0; // <-- is now a flop assigned in always_ff
                next_trig = 1'b1; // <-- update value
                next_count = 32'b0; // <-- update value
                nextState = WaitS;
            end
        WaitS:
            // ... replace trig/distance with next_trig/next_distance in here ...
        WaitS2:
            begin
              // ...
              //count++;  // <-- NOPE would be asynchronous feedback
              next_count = count + 1; // <-- synchronous increment
              // ...
            end
        ReturnS:
            //  ... replace distance with next_distance in here ...
        default:
            nextState = BeginS;
        endcase
     end
```